# How to configure https on deployment yaml file for asp.net core app locally in minikube?

Tags: asp.net-core, kubernetes, asp.net-core-mvc, kubectl, minikube

I have an ASP.NET Core app that I want to configure with HTTPS in my local kubernetes clustur using minikube.

The deployment yaml file is:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: kube-volume
  labels:
    app: kube-volume-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector: 
    matchLabels:
      component: web
  template:
    metadata: 
      labels:
        component: web
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: ckubevolume
          image: kubevolume
          imagePullPolicy: Never
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
            - containerPort: 443
          env:
            - name: ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT
              value: Development
            - name: ASPNETCORE_URLS
              value: https://+:443;http://+:80
            - name: ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT
              value: '443'
            - name: ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password
              value: mypass123
            - name: ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path
              value: /app/https/aspnetapp.pfx
          volumeMounts:
            - name: ssl
              mountPath: "/app/https"
      volumes:
        - name: ssl
          configMap:
            name: game-config
```

You can see i have added **environment variables** for https in yaml file.

I also created a service for this deployment. The yaml file of the service is:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: service-1
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    component: web
  ports:
    - name: http
      protocol: TCP
      port: 100
      targetPort: 80
    - name: https
      protocol: TCP
      port: 200
      targetPort: 443
```

But unfortunately the app is not opening by the service when I run the **minikube service service-1** command.

However when I remove the env variables for https then the app is opening by the service. These are the lines which when I remove the app opens:

```
- name: ASPNETCORE_URLS
  value: https://+:443;http://+:80
- name: ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT
  value: '443'
- name: ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password
  value: mypass123
- name: ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path
  value: /app/https/aspnetapp.pfx
```

I also confirmed with the shell that the certificate is present in the /app/https folder.

Whay I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your approach does not fit well with the architecture of Kubernetes. A TLS certificate (for https) is coupled to a hostname.

I would recommend one of two different approaches:

- Expose your app with a Service of `type: LoadBalancer`
- Expose your app with an [Ingress resource](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/)

### Expose your app with a Service of type LoadBalancer

This is typically called a Network LoadBalancer as it exposes your app for TCP or UDP directly.

See [LoadBalancer access](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/accessing/#loadbalancer-access) in the Minikube documentation. But beware that your app get an external address from your LoadBalancer, and your TLS certificate probably has to match that.

### Expose your app with an Ingress resource

This is the most common approach for Microservices in Kubernetes. In addition to your Service of `type: NodePort` you also need to create an [Ingress resource](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) for your app.

The cluster needs an Ingress controller and the gateway will handle your TLS certificate, instead of your app.

See [How to use custom TLS certificate with ingress addon](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/tutorials/custom_cert_ingress/) for how to configure both Ingress and TLS certificate in Minikube.

I would recommend to go this route.

Comment: Thank you for this wonderful answer. I have a question, even on using an Ingress I would still have to use the environment varaible for configuring the HTTPS ports on my app. But for my case they seem to not work. What do you think can be the problem here?

Comment: Nope, when using Ingress, the HTTPS-connection is terminated in the gateway. From the gateway to the app within the cluster, only HTTP is used, so that app doesn't need any certificate - only the gateway.